# How to sed only that lines that contains given string?

Tags: sed, awk

INPUT:

```
Select ASDF 325 sdfg sdflk lk
Select TRG 46sdg rasdftz fsgs 45
Select ASDF 6ffg sdfg 4456 sdrg
```

OUTPUT:

```
Select ASDF 325 XXXX sdflk lk
Select TRG 46sdg rasdftz fsgs 45
Select ASDF 6ffg XXXX 4456 sdrg
```

So in short I need to "sed" "sdfg" to "XXXX". 

BUT: only in lines that contains the "Select ASDF" string.. How can I do this? (sed, awk, etc. :\ )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can prefix most sed commands with an [address](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=1&format=html#Sed_Addresses) to limit the lines to which they apply. An address can be a line number, or a regex delimited by `/`.

```
cat INPUT | sed '/Select ASDF/ s=sdfg=XXXX='
```

As mentioned Peter.O, the command as written above will substitute the first occurrence of any `sdfg` in the string containing `Select ASDF`. If you need to substitute the exact match to `sdfg` only in the case it is in fourth column you should go this way:

```
cat INPUT | sed 's/\(^Select ASDF [^ ]* \)sdfg /\1XXXX /'
```

Comment: What about another field containing *sdfg*? eg. *5sdfga*

Comment: Hmm, actually that's not the problem too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: are there any options for using: sed '/Select ASDF/g s=sdfg=XXXX=' - so I need to replace all the occurences in a line, not just the first one. but sed gives error if I use "g"

Comment: You need to type `g` after last `=` (at the end of `s` command). It will be like this: `sed '/Select ASDF/ s=sdfg=XXXX=g'`

Answer (score 7):

If you're only changing column 4 if it has the exact value, then using equality operators instead of regular expressions makes sense.

```
awk '$1 == "Select" && $2 == "ASDF" && $4 == "sdfg" {$4 = "XXXX"} {print}'
```

Comment: *Fast!* .. comparing it, for 1 million lines,  with Birei's awk and Rush's *positional* sed:  *0m1.580s*  vs. *0m3.792s* vs. *0m6.740s*

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } 
    /^select asdf/ { 
        sub( /\<sdfg\>/, "XXXX", $0 ) 
    } 
    { print }
' infile
```

Output:

```
Select ASDF 325 XXXX sdflk lk
Select TRG 46sdg rasdftz fsgs 45
Select ASDF 6ffg XXXX 4456 sdrg
```

---

**UPDATE**: Avoid `IGNORECASE` for a non-GNU `awk`, and match case-sensitive. Thanks to **jw013**, who pointed out that detail:

```
awk ' 
    /^Select ASDF/ { 
        sub( /\<sdfg\>/, "XXXX", $0 ) 
    } 
    { print }
' infile
```

Comment: You should mention `IGNORECASE` is a GNU `awk` / `gawk` extension.

Comment: @jw013: Thank you. Updated answer with your suggestion.

Comment: IGNORECASE is wrong in this case, whether it's GNU or G'not.. The criterion in the question is explicitly for upper-case `ASDF`